# TFS issue in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tfs

In android application development i am using TFS(team foundation server) on my eclipse, i am updating my code and resource images, audio files then clicking on Check In Pending Changes, now my code is running fine but when i am clicking on Get Latest Version i am getting old images.

Is there any option to avoid this kind of the issues. and can any one give me some information like

1. How to remove TFS plugin from my eclipse.
2. How to use Go Offline and Go online.

.

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstall TFS plug-in is same as any other plugin in eclipse. Please follow the steps in this page

[http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in?)

Replace the instruction about "About Eclipse" with "About ADT".

2) To go offline, open up "Team Foundation Server Exploring" perspective. Click on Connect to project sand deselect all projects. Click Finish.